# Reporting in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, report

I have `report generating` in my `first` node application. I used `mongodb` and `express`. I have three collections: `salary rule`, `Leave` and `Employee`. I want to generate `employees salary` by using these collections.

I found `phantomjs` to export pdf. I used `ejs` template to generate html.

I got json values from the following scenario.

- find Salary rule
- find All Employees
- find all Leaves by date range.
- Match employees and leaves by employee id and calculate the salary.
- put the result json into the array and generate html by ejs
- export html to pdf by using phantomjs.

I am confused that this scenario could be `hit performance` and `error-prone`. I cannot find any suitable examples for exporting in `node` and `mongodb`.

My question is-

1. Is it `bad idea` to use mongodb in this scenario or is it `normal flow`?
2. Or do I need to change my mongodb `collection schema`?

Leave

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    description: String,
    type: String, // paid or unpaid
    empName : String,
    empId : String
});
```

Employee

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: String,
    name: String,
    basicSalary: Number,
    active: Boolean
});
```

Salary Rule

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    totalHoliday: Number,
    overtimeFee: Number,
    unpaidLeaveFee: Number
});
```

Comment: Can you post your collection schemas and/or a sample document of each?

Comment: The flow you gave above is what your business needs, so as long as that reflects your business, it's normal.

Comment: Just my 2-cent input, you can create Report Schema to calculate all the necessary information, and dump that Report into ejs template. No need to put it temporary into json array. This way, you can write spec tests to cover your business better.

Comment: @autobot_101 so I have to create another schema for report and I have to update this report schema every CRUD of Employee or Leave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO looks like exporting your data to a Relational Database could be easy to generate the report.

BUT if you still want to do this with MongoDB you could do a mapReduce.
 https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/

your last two steps are the same but change the way that you get the data.